# Is it a problem that my furnace filter is loose in its slot?

Tags: hvac, furnace, air-filter

When I bought my home, my furnace had a 16x20x1 nominal-size filter installed, and that's what I've been buying for replacements. This size doesn't fit the opening very well; there are large gaps around the sides. I measured the opening at 16"x20"x1-1/4".

I assume that the gaps are a problem, as they will allow unfiltered air into the furnace. What can I do to eliminate them?

[image: filter with gaps around the sides]

[image: filter cavity without filter installed]

**Here's a picture of the filter's position when the furnace is on. I can still see the gaps around the edges:**
[image: filter position with the furnace on and ingesting air]

**This picture shows the entire slot -- note that there is no "door" or "panel" to close**
[image: wide shot of the slot]

Comment: take another picture when the blower is running

Comment: @jsotola Added a picture. I don't see any difference, myself.

Comment: I wonder if the previous owner lost the cover for the filter slot (accidentally or otherwise). I would think that you would want this covered to help pull air from throughout the house's cold air return system instead of just the basement or the furnace closet or wherever this is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those gaps are normal and don't usually cause a problem. When the furnace is running the air pressure forces the filter against the downstream face of the slot, effectively sealing the opening.

Also, it's not critical that you have a complete seal. The air in your home isn't (or shouldn't be) particularly dusty. It's important that *most* of the dust gets caught before it passes through the fan and heat exchanger(s), but it's not required to have clinically clean air.

They're pretty much all this way. If the filter was to fit tightly enough to create a seal against both faces it would be extremely difficult to install them.  The alternative would be some sort of clamping mechanism like you'd see on a car engine, but it's just not that critical.

Comment: Pic #3 was taken with the furnace on, and it doesn’t seem to be making a difference. That said, my filters do seem dirty when I replace them, so I guess they must be doing some good. Thanks!

Comment: That's because you had the panel open. With it closed there's more pressure against the filter.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like the real problem. There's no "panel" -- this is outside the furnace enclosure, and the gap for the filter doesn't have any cover to shut. I've added a picture to demonstrate. There's even a matching 1"+ gap on the rear side of the duct, as seen in picture #2.

Comment: Ah. Yes, that slot is usually at the top of the duct and there's a panel that lays in place over it. If you don't need that air evacuation you might look at how you can close it. I'm not sure whether that's appropriate for your overall HVAC system plan.

Comment: Thanks! I just ordered this product to help seal up the gaps. The product images look just like my setup -- filter slides in from the side, with no cover. https://www.amazon.com/AllergyZone-AZFL-100-Filter-Lock-Cover/dp/B00PKS6MT0

Comment: I think your answer is an opinion. Saying things like “they are normal” “don’t usually cause a problem “, “it’s not critical to have a complete seal”, “air in your home isn’t (or shouldn’t be) particularly dusty” “it’s important that most of the dust gets caught “ are all opinions. My sister has 3 cats and a dog and I change her filter monthly. If that dust got on her heating elements the efficiency of her unit would be significantly less. Terms like “most of the dust gets caught before it passes through the fan and heat exchanger” is your opinion and WILL reduce the units efficiency over time

Comment: It's not opinion when I have millions of furnaces in homes throughout my high-usage region just like that working fine and dandy. Is it ideal? No. Is there some leakage that has some effect on motor lifespan? Sure. Is it critical that it get fixed? Not for most folks. YMMV. Vote as you like and write your own answer. No hard feelings here.

Answer (score 2):

The opening around this filter would allow air to enter from the space the duct is in. This air will be from the non-conditioned space and should not enter the air handler even if it passes through the filter. It will cause the filter to get clogged sooner.

I would seal it with wide tape whenever a new filter is put in. Tape could stop the filter moving toward the air handler (by adhering to the edge of the filter) so cover inside of the tape that could stick to the cardboard edge of the filter. You could cut a piece of sheet metal to cover the opening and seal that with tape.

Answer (score 1):

That slot is designed for a cut-to-fit filter. You can have your HVAC people cut a new slot that will fit a standard (better) filter.

Comment: There is custom fit furnace filter material available? That's very unexpected. Could you point to where one might find this available to purchase? I've not heard of that in the US.

Comment: I have seen some cut-to-fit filter media.